# Read data directly from gz resource

Tags: php, file, gzip

I have a resource variable `$resource` holding stream of .gz file.
If i write it down as a file by

```
file_put_contents('experiment.gz', $resource);
```

And then read that file as

```
$handle = gzopen('experiment.gz', 'r');
while ($line = gzgets($handle)) {
    echo $line;
}
```

I get data i need, perfectly readable.
But if i try to read directly from resource as

```
while ($line = gzgets($resource)) {
    echo $line;
}
```

I receive lines of encoded data, what am i missing ?

Comment: `file_put_contents` perfectly works with resource as data parameter, as stated in official documentation.

Comment: I apologise, I didn't know that functionality existed.